# How to upload a mp3 with some data from android to server?

Tags: java, android

I want to upload a mp3 file from android with some data to server. Here I need to send some parameter with that mp3 file at same time. I have searched a lot about it but dont get the proper result. If any one have any idea, example about it please share with me. I am indeed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A simple google search shows lots of ideas to accomplish this. Which ones have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Use this code to upload along with other parameter.

```
private void uploadVideo(String audioPath,String param1,String param2) throws ParseException, IOException {

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                //post request to send the video 
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("your url of server");
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy( policy);
                FileBody audio_file1 = new FileBody(new File(audiopath));
                StringBody param1 = new StringBody("your parameter1");
                StringBody param21 = new StringBody("your parameter2");

                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
                reqEntity.addPart("argument that your server take", audio_file1);
                reqEntity.addPart("argument that your server take", param1);
                reqEntity.addPart("argument that your server take", param2);

                httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

                // DEBUG
                System.out.println( "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine( ) );
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httppost );
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity( );

                // DEBUG
                System.out.println( response.getStatusLine( ) );
                if (resEntity != null) {
                  System.out.println( EntityUtils.toString( resEntity ) );
                } // end if
                if (resEntity != null) {
                  resEntity.consumeContent( );
                } // end if

                httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( );
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your asynctask:

```
File yourfile= new File(your path on sdcard);
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(YOUR URL);

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("FileName",new StringBody(yourfile));
entity.addPart("FileDescription",new StringBody(yourfileName));

httpost.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
```